# GeoPandas: Error plotting after clipping shapefile

Tags: python, clip, geopandas, shapely, linestring

I am interested in plotting data on the city of Göteborg (in English Gothenburg, Sweden). I am starting with shapefiles of Sweden and then clipping them to concentrate my study in Göteborg.

```
# Extracting Göteborg boundary
boundary = adm_2.loc[(adm_2["NAME_2"] == "Göteborg")].copy()

boundary
>>
    ID_0    ISO NAME_0  ID_1    NAME_1  ID_2    NAME_2  TYPE_2  ENGTYPE_2   NL_NAME_2   VARNAME_2   geometry
246 222 SWE Sweden  21  Västra Götaland 247 Göteborg    Kommuner    Municipality    None    None    MULTIPOLYGON (((12.09368 57.67838, 12.09466 57...


# Clipping the shapefiles
roads = geopandas.clip(roads_sweden, boundary)
buildings = geopandas.clip(buildings_sweden, boundary)

#roads.shape #(9747, 7)
#roads_sweden.shape #(148403, 7)

#buildings.shape #(1163, 4)
#buildings_sweden.shape #(15253, 4)
```

If I plot ALL the roads, i.e roads_sweden. I have plot of the rows of all Sweden. However, when trying to plot just the roads in Göteborg I get the error:

**IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed**

I can't understand why while they look the same. I even attempted resetting the index but this seems unrelated.

For the plot I'm using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10), facecolor='white', edgecolor='k')
boundary.plot(ax=ax, facecolor= "white", edgecolor="black", linewidth=.5)
roads.plot(ax=ax)
buildings.plot(ax=ax)
```

Even when done individualy, i.e. roads.plot(), I get the error. roads_sweden.plot() always works fine.

Here's some preview of the data

```
roads_sweden.head()

>>
osm_id  name    ref type    oneway  maxspeed    geometry
0   1240    KlensmedsvÃ¤gen None    unclassified    0   0   LINESTRING (17.99027 59.29686, 17.99182 59.296...
1   1241    HyvelvÃ¤gen None    residential 0   0   LINESTRING (17.99273 59.29666, 17.99212 59.295...
2   1242    SpikvÃ¤gen  None    residential 0   0   LINESTRING (17.99353 59.29640, 17.99299 59.295...
3   1243    BultvÃ¤gen  None    residential 0   0   LINESTRING (17.99439 59.29617, 17.99385 59.295...
4   1245    TÃ¥ngvÃ¤gen None    residential 0   0   LINESTRING (17.99691 59.29512, 17.99637 59.294...

roads.head()

>>
osm_id  name    ref type    oneway  maxspeed    geometry
0   3846609 None    None    motorway_link   1   0   LINESTRING (12.09100 57.67369, 12.09090 57.673...
1   4040303 E6  None    motorway    0   0   LINESTRING (12.00496 57.84283, 12.00525 57.841...
2   4040436 None    None    motorway_link   1   0   LINESTRING (12.00643 57.79800, 12.00560 57.796...
3   4040439 None    E 20    motorway    1   0   LINESTRING (11.99463 57.71530, 11.99492 57.715...
4   4040441 None    E 20    motorway    1   0   LINESTRING (11.99520 57.71580, 11.99434 57.71536)
```

**DATA SOURCES**

administrative areas (see area 2): https://www.diva-gis.org/datadown

roads and buildings: https://mapcruzin.com/free-sweden-arcgis-maps-shapefiles.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it myself.
In conclusion, this error is a problem that occurs when osm_id 32947351 is changed to EMPTY after the clip.
And if you check the geometry in the original file, you can see that the value of the linestring is strange. (The start and end points of the line are the same.)

You can check empty rows after operation by using the following command.

```
roads[roads['geometry'].is_empty]
```